# Should I upcast before calling an inherited method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am probably doing something way wrong here, but I have a Base class with multiple derived classes.

```
 public abstract class BaseItem : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public void LevelUp()
        {
           // do some common thing ... maybe increase damage
        }
    }
```

```
 public class RangedWeapon: BaseItem 
    {
      public new void LevelUp()
        {
            base.LevelUp();
            // do specific things here... maybe increase range.
        }
   }
```

```
 public class MeleeWeapon: BaseItem 
    {
      public new void LevelUp()
        {
            base.LevelUp();
            // do specific things here... 
        }
   }
```

In an inventory manager, I have a list of all items, and can call the `LevelUp` method on them. The issue, I think, is that I have a list of `<BaseItem>`s and the specific classes `LevelUp` is not called:

```
public void LevelUpItem(string itemName)
        {
            var item = AvailableItems.First(w => w.ItemName.Equals(itemName));
            
            item.LevelUp();
        }
```

My original thought is that I need to upcast the item before calling the LevelUp function. My second thought is that I'm doing something way wrong here.

My specific question is "How do I upcast safely" and my unasked question is, "should I consider a different approach to polymorphism?"

Comment: Why not mark the base method as `virtual` and `override` the child ones (which is the usual approach)?

Comment: I am somewhat new... does virtual allow for a default implementation? I see it does... I clearly don't know the difference between virtual and non-virtual methods yet.

Comment: Yes, virtual just changes the access for derived types. Make public virtual void on the base and public override void on the derived types.  Base can still have the default implementation.

Comment: Thanks Yall! someone make an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can use [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) keyword (also there is [`abstract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) modifier in case you don't want to have any default implemenation) for [polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism):

```
public abstract class BaseItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void LevelUp()
    {
       // do some common thing ... maybe increase damage
    }
}
```

And use [`override`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) modifier to change the behavior in inheritors:

```
public class RangedWeapon: BaseItem 
{
  public override void LevelUp()
    {
        base.LevelUp();
        // do specific things here... maybe increase range.
    }
}
```